# Compilation failed: Subprocess failed

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

brew install leiningen

I got

```
Compiling joy.gui.DynaFrame
Could not locate joy/gui/DynaFrame__init.class or joy/gui/DynaFrame.clj on classpath:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate joy/gui/DynaFrame__init.class or joy/gui/DynaFrame.clj on classpath: , compiling:(/private/var/folders/zm/swyymlvn4l7__d1rln_n391r0000gn/T/form-init7580966196782799989.clj:1:124)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate joy/gui/DynaFrame__init.class or joy/gui/DynaFrame.clj on classpath:
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)
    at user$eval20$fn__29.invoke(form-init7580966196782799989.clj:1)
    at user$eval20.invoke(form-init7580966196782799989.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 11 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

I tried to reinstall but the issue does not solved.

When I type, 
lein version

I got this:
Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 12 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

I installed Java correctly but not sure where to start to fix this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details.  You have some project reference to `joy.gui.DynaFrame` which is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around and it seems you are trying to run an old [example from *The Joy of Clojure*](https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/master/src/clj/joy/gui/DynaFrame.clj), right?

The example needed a minor touch-up for me to be able to run it.

- I created a new Leiningen project first with `lein new app dynademo`.
- Inside the new project folder, I created the directories for the namespace: `mkdir -p src/joy/gui`
- Created the file `src/joy/gui/DynaFrame.clj`

The Leiningen project that we just created with `lein new ...` uses Clojure 1.10, which doesn't seem to like one thing:

- Replace the line with `:prefix df-` with `:prefix "df-"` (eg. wrap the value `df-` in quotes)

Save the file, and now you can launch the window from the REPL, like this:

```
$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 44037 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:44037
REPL-y 0.4.3, nREPL 0.6.0
Clojure 1.10.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

dynaframe.core=> (compile 'joy.gui.DynaFrame)
joy.gui.DynaFrame
dynaframe.core=> (def hello-frame (joy.gui.DynaFrame. "Hello"))
#'dynaframe.core/hello-frame
dynaframe.core=> (.show hello-frame)
nil
```

It looks like this:

[image: dynaframe example]

(you will need to move/resize the window a bit, but you get the idea). **Note**: I'm using Java 8 (JDK 1.8.0_191) but it *should* work the same in JDK 12.